# WCF / ASP.NET MVC MessagebodyStream to Memory or Filestream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a ASP.NET MVC Website as Frontend  that is connected via WCF (net.tcp streamed response) to a backend running on a different server.

The Backendservice implements a servicecontract that contains the follwoing method

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface BackendService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetDownload(int dataId);
}
```

The service is hosted with the transfermode as streamed Response.

At the frontend I want to offer the ability to Download the file that is streamed from the Backend.

Because the MessageBodyStream returned from the WCFChannel can't be converted automatically to a Filestream and actionresult I tried to convert it to a Memorystream. So I had to read the full MessageBodyStream and copy it to an Memorystream, that can be returned in an Actionresult as FileStreamResult.

```
 public class MyAspNETMVCController:Controller
{
     public FileStreamResult DownloadFile(int DataId)        
     {
         var stream = new MemoryStream();
         var netstream = downloadService.GetDownload(rawDataId);
         netstream.CopyTo(stream);
         stream.Position = 0;
         return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip");
      }
}
```

The Files a try to offer are about 4GB and sometimes I get a OutOfMemory Exception. Is there any "nice" way of getting big data from an WCF streaming service and return them as FileStreamResult to the Client?
I do not want a direct connection between the client and the Backend. The complete communication should run over the ASP.NET MVC Website.

Comment: `netstream.CopyToAsync(stream);`does not work. I get a File containing 0 Bytes for Download.

Comment: Try `stream.Flush();` after setting the Position

Comment: does not work, the outOfMemoryException is thrown on `netstream.CopyTo(stream);` call when using `CopyTo` and files still have 0 Bytes when using `CopyToAsync`

Comment: Ah right, I looked over the important part at the end, my apologies. You could page. You could page the stream, or return the archive size in chunks.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I'm very new to MVC and WCF.